# HERE Android SDK, Violation Notes are not retuning violation notes array

Tags: here-api

HERE Android SDK is not returning violation notes array, if there are violation on the route (for example Weight Violation) But HERE api /routing/7.2/calculateroute return that array. Is there any way to return similar data via SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Notes array is not available from SDK, the closest you could get is ViolatedOption enum from RouteResult. It does not seem to include a weight specific violation though (https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/RouteResult.ViolatedOption.html)